# Prestashop - Change mobile menu respond width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am using Prestashop 1.7.2.4 to develop an ecommerce site. I want to override the default mobile menu width from 767px to 990px. How can I achieve this?

If I remove footer javascripts, the mobile logo disappears. Is it controlled by scripting?

Answer (score 1):

I researched found the solution. Replaced `responsive.min_width` value in **/prestashop/themes/[theme]/assets/js/theme.js** and commented the following code in **/prestashop/themes/[theme]/assets/css/theme.css**

```
/*@media (max-width:767px){.hidden-sm-down{display:none!important}}*/

/*@media (min-width:768px){.hidden-md-up{display:none!important}}*/
```

Add responsive css code in **/prestashop/themes/[theme]/assets/css/custom.css**

```
@media (max-width:990px){.hidden-sm-down{display:none!important}}
@media (min-width:991px){.hidden-md-up{display:none!important}}
@media (max-width:990px){#header .header-nav .top-logo{line-height:50px;vertical-align:middle;width:200px;margin:0 auto}}
```

Comment: Remember to clear cache for effect to take place( both in CMS and on page )